# asp.net MVC data model validation on double

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, validation

I'm using datamodel validation on my asp.net MVC website and I encountered an error.

My model looks like this:

```
public class MyModel{
  public String Name{get;set;}
  public double? Value {get;set;}
}
```

It works fine in most case, but if I've a decimal value in the "Value" field, like "5.5", I got a validation error.

The website is running under the "Fr-FR" locale. I tried "5.5" or "5,5", they both don't work but I got different messages:

```
La valeur '5.5' n'est pas valide pour Value.
```

which should mean `"The value '5.5' isn't valide for Value"`

And

```
Le champ Value doit être un nombre.
```

Which means `"The field Value has to be a number"`

The only "logic that I've in my code behind is that I use "`ModelState.IsValid`" before doing an update.

Why is this not working and what should I do to correct this problem?

**Important edit**
By debugging I saw that fields of my models comes "NULL" when having numbers with decimals.

Comment: "5,5" is definitely a good response because it is not a number. I am looking into if you are having an issue with the type double?

Comment: do you get the same result with other non ints? (e.g. 2.25). The issue might be with the validation expecting an int instead of a double.

Comment: @JohnSykor In fact 5,5 is not so false because with FR locale, it's the official separator.

Comment: @Ammar-whynotZoidberg Yes, with any double I get those problem. Why the validation would like to have an int?

Comment: have you tried temporary changing the locale to EN and seeing if it works?

Comment: Yes I tried, and it works! But I cant do this, it's a localized website

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact the problem is that the client validation seems to works with EN culture and the server with the fr-FR validation.

So I wrote a simple modelBinder which is culture invariant:

```
public class NullableDoubleModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        ValueProviderResult valueResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
        ModelState modelState = new ModelState { Value = valueResult };
        object actualValue = null;
        if (valueResult.AttemptedValue != null)
        {
            try
            {
                actualValue = Convert.ToDouble(valueResult.AttemptedValue, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            }
            catch (FormatException e)
            {
                modelState.Errors.Add(e);
            }
        }



        bindingContext.ModelState.Add(bindingContext.ModelName, modelState);
        return actualValue;
    }
}
```

And I register it in the Global.asax file:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
   //Other stuff
   ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(double?), new NullableDoubleModelBinder());
}
```

And now it works :)

Answer (score 1):

To mimic your error my model looks like

```
public class MyModel{
  public String Name{ get; set; }
  public int? Value { get; set; }
}
```

Please review your code and maybe make an edit because **when int is changed to double**, 5.5 will work fine unless your controller or model has some other code in it that is causing this validation.

Comment: Like I said, my model has a double, and I'm doing nothing else than an if(ModelState.IsValid){//Persist changes} in my controller. I've no special data annotation in my model too